# PHP execute command line tool to print html content

Tags: php, command-line, window, exec

I am using a command line tool to auto print a dynamic page using php exec but unfortunately due to hard disk failure I have reinstall the window and after that that auto print feature is not working although exec funtion is working fine but when i am executing that .exe file nothing printed

Tool which using is

http://www.printhtml.com/

When i am executing it in command line it is printing fine like this

```
D:\printhtmlnew>printhtml.exe printername='192.168.1.1' url='192.168.1.2/test.html'
```

Auto print is working fine after executing this command in command line

But when i am executing in php like this

```
exec("D://printhtmlnew/printhtml.exe printername='192.168.1.1' url=192.168.1.2/test.html",$out);

print_r($out);
```

Only showing copyright and version information .When it was working it was showing that print was successfully sent to printer.

I check safe mode in php.ini and exec funtion disable

Comment: `D:\\printhtmlnew>`...that's the prompt in your command window, generated by the CMD software. It shows you where to type. It's not part of the actual command! Remove that from the `exec` call and try again.

Comment: sorry it was copy paste issue i have edited the question and corrected the path of the exe now it is D://printhtmlnew/printhtml.exe

Comment: It seems the shell will just ignore it, but `D://printhtmlnew` should not have two slashes. It's a Windows path, not a URL. And you don't run the exact same commands in both cases. In any case, if you see program output, it can be something related to that specific program rather than a PHP problem per se.